# Postgres collation on aliased field

Tags: postgresql, internationalization, collation

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE public_bodies
  ("id" int, "name" varchar(46))
;

INSERT INTO public_bodies
  ("id", "name")
VALUES
  (1, 'Ytre Helgeland District Psychiatric Centre'),
  (2, 'Åfjord Municipality'),
  (3, 'Østfold Hospital')
;
```

I'd like to run this query:

```
SELECT public_bodies.id, public_bodies.name AS display_name
FROM public_bodies
ORDER BY display_name COLLATE "en_US";
```

But I get this error:

```
ERROR:  column "display_name" does not exist
LINE 3: ORDER BY display_name COLLATE "en_US";
                 ^
```

Ordering by the table name works fine:

```
SELECT public_bodies.id, public_bodies.name AS display_name
FROM public_bodies
ORDER BY public_bodies.name COLLATE "en_US";

--  id |        display_name
-- ----+--------------------------------------------
--   2 | Åfjord Municipality
--   3 | Østfold Hospital
--   1 | Ytre Helgeland District Psychiatric Centre
```

Ordering on the alias works okay too:

```
SELECT public_bodies.id, public_bodies.name AS display_name
FROM public_bodies
ORDER BY display_name;

--  id |        display_name
-- ----+--------------------------------------------
--   2 | Åfjord Municipality
--   3 | Østfold Hospital
--   1 | Ytre Helgeland District Psychiatric Centre
```

Applying the `COLLATE` before assigning the alias works, but I don't understand why this is different to collating after the `ORDER_BY`.

```
SELECT public_bodies.id, public_bodies.name COLLATE "en_US" AS display_name
FROM public_bodies
ORDER BY display_name;

--  id |        display_name
-- ----+--------------------------------------------
--   2 | Åfjord Municipality
--   3 | Østfold Hospital
--   1 | Ytre Helgeland District Psychiatric Centre
```

Postgres version:

```
SELECT version();
                                               version
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 9.1.12 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3, 64-bit
```

I've get the same results on SQL fiddle (Postgres 9.3).

Why can't Postgres collate on the aliased field?

Comment: In Postgresql you probably can't use an alias in the order clause at all

Comment: Just updated the question – ordering by the alias without any collation is fine.

Comment: Smells like a bug. Have you tried it in the current release, 9.4.4?

Comment: It doesn't work on 9.4.4 either.

Answer (score 2):

It's the way the language is defined. `COLLATE` clauses apply to *expressions*, and this case doesn't qualify.

By "expression", I mean some collection of operators, functions, variable identifiers, literals, etc., combined to produce an output value. In other words, the general class of value-producing "things" which are allowed to appear as a function argument, as a `SELECT` field definition, in a `VALUES` list, and so on.

A `COLLATE` clause may be attached to an expression, and an expression may appear in an `ORDER BY` list, but it's not the *only* thing allowed in an `ORDER BY` list; you can also include the [names or positions of output columns](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-select.html#SQL-ORDERBY), but these are treated as a distinct case by the parser.

The reason they need to be treated differently is that the query's output field identifiers are not in [scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29) while evaluating expressions; this is why something like `ORDER BY display_name || 'x'` comes back with `column "display_name" does not exist`. To work around this, bare field names in the `ORDER BY` list are compared against the output list before expression evaluation is even attempted, but as a consequence, nothing more complex than a bare field name is accepted in this context (and that includes an attached `COLLATE` clause).